# How to create an NSDictionary and Write and Read the information from a NSUserDefaults object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults, saving-data

I want to store 3 variables all of type Int for a game (gameLevel,time,clicks). I want to save the values of these variables in one UIViewController at the end of the game, and pass it to another UIViewController that will present the gameScore (using UILabel).

Should I use an NSDictionary object for this task? and how do I create an NSUserDefaults object and pass it the NSDictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the values in `NSUserDefaults` when game ends

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(gameLevel, forKey: "gameLevelKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(time, forKey: "timeKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(clicks, forKey: "clicksKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Get the saved values from `NSUserDefaults` in other view controller

```
let gameLevel = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("gameLevelKey")
let time = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("timeKey")
let clicks = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("clicksKey")
```

[**`NSUserDefaults`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) is like database where you can save values using `setXXX` method and retrieve values using the `xxxForKey` method